# DPDK Crypto Device Scheduler "Capability Update Failed"

Tags: encryption, dpdk

I am working on a DPDK project and experience issues that need you help.
The project needs to implement encryption/decryption through DPDK (multi-buffer library). To support all cipher and hash algorithms, I need create 4 type of virtual devices: crypto_null, crypto_aesni_mb, crypto_snow3g and crypto_zuc. I tried to create a crypto-scheduler to manage all 4 devices. When the devices attach to the scheduler, it failed. I can reproduce the exact same failure with the DPDK example program: l2fwd_crypto.

Here is the command I use to run l2fwd_crypto.

./l2fwd-crypto -l 0-1 -n 4 --vdev "crypto_aesni_mb0" --vdev "crypto_null" --vdev "crypto_zuc" --vdev "crypto_snow3g0" --vdev "crypto_scheduler,slave=crypto_null,slave=crypto_aesni_mb0,slave=crypto_snow3g0,slave=crypto_zuc" -- -p 0x3 --chain CIPHER_HASH --cipher_op ENCRYPT --cipher_algo aes-cbc --cipher_key 00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e:0f --auth_op GENERATE --auth_algo aes-xcbc-mac --auth_key 10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:1f

The error message is:

rte_cryptodev_scheduler_slave_attach() line 214: capabilities update failed

I am using DPDK 20.05 on CentOS 7.4

My question is:

1. Is this the correct way to handle all different crypto algorithm? I mean create 4 virtual devices.
2. Why the crypto scheduler failed?

Any suggestion/comments are really appreciated.

Comment: can you please re-test the same with similar HW/SW capability. That is either all device as `null, or snow, zuc`. As far I read https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/cryptodevs/scheduler.html the crypto scheduler is for scheduling between same crypto devices which can be SW, HW or both. But not for different cyrpto algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With the same crypto algorithms, it works. It is the limit of the scheduler.

Comment: I will update the answer in the comment. Please accept and upvote as it will help others

Comment: if you find the information please accept and upvote to help to close the ticket and help others who might be seeking similar information.

Comment: can you please accept and upvote to close the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT-1: Based on comment conversation]

DPDK POLL mode Crypto Scheduler is intended to be running with either HW or SW of the same type. This is covered in [dpdk document](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/cryptodevs/scheduler.html). Hence if one needs to Crypto scheduler to work, it has to initialized with all same type (either HW/SW).

Hence re-running the test with either all NULL, ZUC, SNoW, AES_MB will work

note: with respect to internally logic working, my personal opinion is the current logic in crypto-scheduler logic is correct. Because, in actual logic one will lookup dest-ip or src+dest IP in either ACL, LPM, or Exact Match to identify the SA or Crypto keys. this can offloaded to SW or HW depending upon work load or flow (mice or elephant) flow.